# Xamarin iOS Release build Error - "Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac Version 7.6.7 (build 49)"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, release-builds

I have a project which was working fine and I was able to prepare and distribute the build with old Visual Studio for Mac.

When I update to the latest version of Visual Studio, then the problem starts happening.

With new Visual Studio, I am not able to prepare a Release build with option "Archive for publishing",

It shows random error logs below :

```
lipo : error : unable to find utility "lipo", not a developer tool or in PATH
MTOUCH : error MT5306: Failed to create the a fat library. Please review the build log.

Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
```

Also, it sometimes shows error like below :

[image]

Is there any solution for this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you update the Xcode?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I got exactly the same..

Comment: @AlexShvets: I updated the latest version of visual studio which requires latest Xcode, so I kept 2 Xcode in my Application folder at that time. My workaround was, delete the OLD Xcode and Use the latest one. Keep "Xcode" one copy and use its reference path.

Answer (score -1):

You have conflicts of versions, it's mostly Android side that causes it. Go to Android project, and right click on properties and check or fiddle with Android versions... then clean and build.